# NodeJS + ExpressJS listen connection error

Tags: node.js, express, ipv6

I am getting the following error when I try and connect to my ExpressJS

```
error: Command failed: host ::ffff:XX.XXX.X.XX
```

I am trying to get the app to also allow IPv6 access.

Old code

```
httpsServer.listen(9000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
        console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 9000');
});
```

new code

```
httpsServer.listen(9000,'::', () => {
        console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 9000');
});
```

Comment: An address in the `::ffff:XX.XXX.X.XX` format is _not_ an IPv6 address. It is an IPv4-Mapped address, meaning it is an IPv4 address in the IPv6 format. Those addresses are meant to allow a common data store for both IPv4 an IPv6 addresses, but they cannot actually be used for network traffic. If you want to use IPv6, then you either need to use a Global IPv6 address (in the `2000::/3` range) or a ULA IPv6 address (the `fd00::/8` range) can be locally assigned if the next 40 bits are randomly chosen.

Comment: I worked out what part of my app was crashing it, I am now trying to fix it.